# UIWebView, enable touch hold save image, like in mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiwebview

I'd like to enable Save Image and Copy when a user touch-holds an image in a UIWebView in my app. Is there a property that will enable this or will I need to write some special methods to accomplish this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: check this link http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/5109242276/tutorial-customise-uiwebview-menu

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImage * downloadImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(downloadImage,nil, nil, nil);
    [downloadImage release];

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved" message:@"Wallpaper saved to your Gallery." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];

Add this whole code to your long press method, it will save your image in gallery.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by creating and attaching the UILongPressGestureRecognizer instance to the button.

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
 [self.button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
 [longPress release];
```

And then implement the method that handles the gesture

```
 - (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
     NSLog(@"Long Press");

 //do something
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to make the image pressed in UIWebView a button?

Comment: just tricky like you can put over a webview Constome Button then you can get event of UIButton... :)