# iPhone webapp disabling touch & hold to save image

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile

I'm having a little issue.
I have a mobile web-app for iPhone...
My mobile site needs users to be able to touch and hold an image to save it to their phone..
However, when opened as a web-app , unlike just the regular safari browsers, when you touch a hold and image, the dialog for save image does not appear.

I NEED this dialog to appear when touching and holding images...

Any help to get it working?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

First detect the user clicking on images and actually find out the images url they are clicking on. After That Use below code to download and save the image. For Detecting image Use the code from this link : [Customise Uiwebview](http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/5109242276/tutorial-customise-uiwebview-menu).

```
UIImage * downloadImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(downloadImage,nil, nil, nil);


UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved" message:@"Wallpaper saved to your Gallery." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
```

it will save your image in gallery.

Source : [UIWebView, enable touch hold save image, like in mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912617/uiwebview-enable-touch-hold-save-image-like-in-mobile-safari)

Also you can try this link : [Customise Uiwebview](http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/5109242276/tutorial-customise-uiwebview-menu)

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding... 
But its a web-app... html based...
Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Did you checked Customise UIwebview Link: http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/5109242276/tutorial-customise-uiwebview-menu  here someone using some javascript  (`JStools.js`) to detect the image link. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you have to Use some Plugin,  e.g : If you are using Phonegap there is a plugin called Child Browser (not sure as i used Before 8 months).